# pipenv - updating index url in pipfile

Tags: python, pip, pipenv

What pipenv command should I run to replace the below url?

```
[[source]]
name = "pypi"
url = "https://pypi.org/simple"
```

I tried running the below command but it is not updating the url

```
pipenv update --pypi-mirror "<url>"
```

Comment: Why not edit the file and replace it?

Comment: yes , i could do that , but wanted to check if there is an option to do it from command prompt as well.

Comment: No. Just edit the file.

Comment: Thank @pradyunsg & kichik